# How to group consecutive NaN values from a Pandas Series in a set of slices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan

I want to merge consecutive `NaN` values into slices. Is there a simple way of doing this with numpy or pandas?

```
l = [
    (996, np.nan), (997, np.nan), (998, np.nan),
    (999, -47.3), (1000, -72.5), (1100, -97.7),
    (1200, np.nan), (1201, np.nan), (1205, -97.8),
    (1300, np.nan), (1302, np.nan), (1305, -97.9),
    (1400, np.nan), (1405, -97.10), (1408, np.nan)
]
l = pd.Series(dict(l))
```

Expected result:

```
[
    (slice(996, 999, None), array([nan, nan, nan])),
    (999, -47.3),
    (1000, -72.5),
    (1100, -97.7),
    (slice(1200, 1202, None), array([nan, nan])),
    (1205, -97.8),
    (slice(1300, 1301, None), array([nan])),
    (slice(1302, 1303, None), array([nan])),
    (1305, -97.9),
    (slice(1400, 1401, None), array([nan])),
    (1405, -97.1),
    (slice(1408, 1409, None), array([nan]))
]
```

A numpy array with two dimensions would be OK as well, rather than a list of tuples

**Update 2019/05/31**: I have just realised that if I just use a dictionary instead of a Pandas Series the algorythm is much more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is full or corner cases, nan equality, first element of each pair being a slice or a single value, second being a np.array or a single value.

For so complex requirements, I would just rely on a plain Python non vectorized way:

```
def trans(ser):
    def build(last, cur, val):
        if cur == last + 1:
            if np.isnan(val):
                return (slice(last, cur), np.array([np.nan]))
            else:
                return (last, val)
        else:
            return (slice(last, cur), np.array([val] * (cur - last)))
    last = ser.iloc[0]
    old = last_index = ser.index[0]
    resul = []
    for i in ser.index[1:]:
        val = ser[i]
        if ((val != last) and not(np.isnan(val) and np.isnan(last))) \
           or i != old + 1:
            resul.append(build(last_index, old + 1, last))
            last_index = i
            last = val
        old = i
    resul.append(build(last_index, old+1, last))
    return resul
```

It gives something close to the expected result:

```
[(slice(996, 999, None), array([nan, nan, nan])),
 (999, -47.3),
 (1000, -72.5),
 (1100, -97.7),
 (slice(1200, 1202, None), array([nan, nan])),
 (1205, -97.8),
 (slice(1300, 1301, None), array([nan])),
 (slice(1302, 1303, None), array([nan])),
 (1305, -97.9),
 (slice(1400, 1401, None), array([nan])),
 (1405, -97.1),
 (slice(1408, 1409, None), array([nan]))]
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion. The indexes 1300, 1302, 1400 and 1402 should not be included in a huge slice as I have written in the expected result, because they are non-consecutive indices. So I would need to make it in a slighly different way

Comment: Ah!! I made a mistake when I wrote the example. Sorry @Serge. In fact, the indices should not be repeated. I have updated my question. Then You may be right with the previous algorythm

Comment: I have updated my original algo to correctly process non consecutive indices.

Comment: I have added one more condition to your code to get the exact expected result. In addition NaN and cells with the same data are group together as well, that's cool. Thank you !!

Comment: I have just realised that if I just use a dictionary instead of a Pandas Series the algorythm is much more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Group by `cumsum` of `notnull` is a good idea, but we need to filter out the first non-null value in each sub-series, so we can groupby the pair `(cumsum, notnull)`:

```
# convert series to frame, 
# don't know why series only doesn't work
df = l.to_frame(name='val')

df['notnull'] = df['val'].notnull()
g = df.groupby([ df['notnull'].cumsum(), 'notnull']).val

[(v.index, v.values) for i, v in g]
```

Out:

```
[(Int64Index([996, 997, 998], dtype='int64'), array([nan, nan, nan])),
 (Int64Index([1200, 1201], dtype='int64'), array([nan, nan])),
 (Int64Index([1300, 1302, 1400, 1402], dtype='int64'),
  array([nan, nan, nan, nan])),
 (Int64Index([999], dtype='int64'), array([-47.3])),
 (Int64Index([1000], dtype='int64'), array([-72.5])),
 (Int64Index([1100], dtype='int64'), array([-97.7])),
 (Int64Index([1202], dtype='int64'), array([-97.1]))]
```

---

Edit: taken the consecutive index in consideration and update for slices:

```
# convert group to slices
def get_slice(x):
    idx_min, idx_max = x.index.min(), x.index.max()

    if len(x) >1:
        return (slice(idx_min, idx_max+1), x.values)
    elif x.isna().any():
        return (slice(idx_min, idx_min+1), x.values)
    else:
        return (idx_min, x[idx_min])

df['notnull'] = df['val'].notnull()

# non-continuous indices
df['sep'] = (df.index != df.index.to_series().shift() + 1).cumsum()

g = df.groupby(['sep', df['notnull'].cumsum(), 'notnull']).val

g.apply(get_slice).values.tolist()
```

gives:

```
[(slice(996, 999, None), array([nan, nan, nan])),
 (999, -47.3),
 (1000, -72.5),
 (1100, -97.7),
 (slice(1200, 1202, None), array([nan, nan])),
 (1205, -97.8),
 (slice(1300, 1301, None), array([nan])),
 (slice(1302, 1303, None), array([nan])),
 (1305, -97.9),
 (slice(1400, 1401, None), array([nan])),
 (1405, -97.1),
 (slice(1408, 1409, None), array([nan]))]
```

Comment: Your solution looks elegant but I would need a final step to convert the array positions into slices, and make separate elements if they are not consecutive. I am afraid there is no vectorized way to achieve it as Serge says in his answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the result is correct now. I have been analyzing how long does it take to finish the processing and the Serge algorythm takes much less (405 µs ± 22.2 µs over 14.5 ms ± 310 µs). So I will stick with his version. Do you thing that the algorythm of yours will be more efficient in the long run?

Comment: Anyway I have upvoted your answer because it is useful